# Animating Android ListView view on touch

Tags: android-listview, android-animation, android

I'd like to animate item in `ListView` when user touches the item and do the animation backwards when the touch have ended.

I've tried doing it by overriding `onTouchEvent` of the list item but if I return true when I handle the event I don't receive `OnItemClickListener` calls anymore because I've consumed the touch event, and if I return false I don't receive callback when user stops touching the view.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            //handle onclick
        }
    });

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.v(TAG, event.getActionMasked() + "");
    if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Animation animation = createColorAnimation(false);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        startAnimation(animation);
        return true;
    } else if(event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
        Animation animation = createColorAnimation(true);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        startAnimation(animation);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

I want to receive `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_CANCEL` events `onTouchEvent` and calls `OnItemClickListener`, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your list adapter in method getView() before returning View v call v.setBackgroundDrawable with a custom Drawable. this Drawable has to be stateful (isStatefull shound return true), overwrite onStateChanged and log StateSet.dump(stateSet), the rest is up to you what you do with each state

Comment: btw with this approach you can animate not only when you touch your item but also when you change selection with the tracball, which makes UX more intuitive