# listView pointToPosition is incorrect 'half the time'

Tags: android

I'm trying to use list.pointToPosition to determine which list item position the user's finger is touching. My list contains a `TextView` followed by a `ListView` in a `RelativeLayout`. The problem that I've discovered is that pointToPosition seems to ignore the fact that I've got a `TextView` and returns the wrong position of the item.

Let me explain further with some pictures and some samples of what's being returned. I've enabled the debug feature that let's me track finger touches. You'll see it in the blue line in the following images.

In the following image, you'll notice at the top of the screen is a TextView labeled "LIGHTS". Just below that is my ListView. Look at the blue line that tracks my finger touch and slide - you'll notice that it starts near the top of the row labeled "Front Porch". Performing "pointToPosition" at that location returns the correct value of 4.

[image: Correct pointToPosition]

Now however, if I start my touch half way down that same row, pointToPosition returns a value of 5. You can see my touch/drag in the following screen shot.

[image: Wrong position]

When I change the size of my TextView to have a height of 1dp, the problem goes away; thus I'm lead to believe that the pointToPosition method assumes that my ListView is the only thing on the page.

I could implement a hack and deal with this by calculating the offset caused by the TextView, but my feeling is that this will eventually come back to bite me when this bug (assuming it's a bug) gets fixed. What I'm wondering is if there's a proper way to fix it.

**Source Code Samples:**

`layout.xml`

```
<com.mls.util.RelativeLayoutTouchInterceptor xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
android:id="@+id/rlRoot" android:clickable="true"
tools:context=".DeviceListActivity" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_header"
          style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
          android:text="Lights"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/dlList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list_header"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
</ListView>

</com.mls.util.RelativeLayoutTouchInterceptor>
```

`RelativeLayoutTouchInterceptor.java`

```
public class RelativeLayoutTouchInterceptor extends RelativeLayout {
    ...

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {

            downStart = MotionEvent.obtain(event);

            ListView list = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.dlList);
            int position = list.pointToPosition((int)downStart.getX(), (int)downStart.getY());
    }

 ...

}
```

Comment: hmm why do you want to use pointToPosition?

Comment: I'm using pointToPosition to perform some horizontal sliding 'gestures' on a listView item.

Comment: so basically you want to detect what list item was pressed down before a fling gesture?

Comment: Yes, I need to know which item is selected, but the fling gesture isn't the gesture I'm trying to track in this case.

Comment: ok, this may be a wild guess but see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999443/animating-android-listview-view-on-touch, hth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you're overriding the `onInterceptTouchEvent` of the `RelativeLayout`, not the `ListView`. It's reporting the y coordinate within the layout itself, which includes the `TextView`.

If you want to get the coordinates relative to the `ListView` only, you could just override it for the `ListView` itself. It is an indirect subclass of `ViewGroup`, so it has access to the method.

There's no bug that will be fixed to worry about, it's working like it should.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and added the perceived hack to fix this of adding the height of the TextView to the Y position provided to `pointToPosition`